Is Stack Exchange violating the GDPR laws by not addressing GDPR related concerns on the Meta site?
In the last few months users posted multiple questions regarding the Data Request procedure that Stack Exchange implements on the network. None of these post ever got an official answer despite multiple employees promising that this "is been looked into" and thus acknowledging the request.
Some examples are:

In the data request page, what does the "Object to Processing" request type do?, posted FOUR months ago, acknowledged by Philippe on July 20 (more than two months ago).
Is the company selling our Personal Information or not?, posted two month ago and acknowledged soon after by Cesar M with a promise to "look into it"
an user started an experiment two months ago to request some data. I lack the full details but the same user pointed out that "There's supposed to be a way to request a full data dump the correct way but as of the date of posting, I'm still waiting on my request to be fulfilled." just today, so at least part of those request weren't fulfilled yet.

I am now trying to determine if this extended denial of information by the company (which seems to be attempting to "sit out" on the answers until hopefully everyone forgets) is already constituting an sanctionable infraction of the GDPR laws.
I know that Article 12 states:


The controller shall take appropriate measures to provide any information referred to in Articles 13 and 14 and any communication under Articles 15 to 22 and 34 relating to processing to the data subject in a concise, transparent, intelligible and easily accessible form, using clear and plain language, in particular for any information addressed specifically to a child. The information shall be provided in writing, or by other means, including, where appropriate, by electronic means. When requested by the data subject, the information may be provided orally, provided that the identity of the data subject is proven by other means.

The controller shall facilitate the exercise of data subject rights under Articles 15 to 22. In the cases referred to in Article 11(2), the controller shall not refuse to act on the request of the data subject for exercising his or her rights under Articles 15 to 22, unless the controller demonstrates that it is not in a position to identify the data subject.

The controller shall provide information on action taken on a request under Articles 15 to 22 to the data subject without undue delay and in any event within one month of receipt of the request. That period may be extended by two further months where necessary, taking into account the complexity and number of the requests. The controller shall inform the data subject of any such extension within one month of receipt of the request, together with the reasons for the delay. Where the data subject makes the request by electronic form means, the information shall be provided by electronic means where possible, unless otherwise requested by the data subject.





If the controller does not take action on the request of the data subject, the controller shall inform the data subject without delay and at the latest within one month of receipt of the request of the reasons for not taking action and on the possibility of lodging a complaint with [the Commissioner] and seeking a judicial remedy.


But I lack the legal experience to evaluate the full picture.
I am therefore curios as if the demonstrable behavior of the company, which de facto refuses to address concerns about its operation and provide transparent and intelligible instructions despite being aware of such concerns as proved by the replies of its employees constitutes a violation of the key principles and nature of the the GDPR laws that could therefore get the company in the position of being sanctioned or prohibited to operate in the European area.

It would be somewhat of a surprise at this point if Stack Exchange was obeying EU law.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


A company which is subject to GDPR has the duty to establish processes on how to handle an information request. For a very small company with little data, these can be as simple as "have a database admin execute queries and dump the result." For a large company with more data, more formalized processes would be expected. Having processes is an obligation towards the data protection authorities in the appropriate member country.
Before handing out personal data in response to an information request, the company has to ascertain if the person making the request really is the person covered by the data. There should be processes for that. If I phone a bank and say "send everything you have on John Doe to this post-office box" they would be negligent to respond.

So there are two questions here, really:

Is a company like Stackexchange allowed to direct data subjects to a specific page for data requests, and if not, which other means of contact do they have to provide (e.g. registered mail)?
I'm not aware of any regulation which requires a company to accept data requests through any channel which can reach any employee, especially if legally satisfactory processes do exist.
If no obligation did exist to accept data requests by postings on Meta, have the responses by employees on Meta created such an obligation? Or did the employees merely promise that the existing processes would be looked into, which might e.g. cause the legal department to check if there are new precedents to consider.
I cannot answer that part.


None of those are data subject requests
The GDPR requires SE to have a legitimate basis for the data processing; it explains what that is in its privacy policy.
It also requires them to respond to certain types of requests from a data subject about their data. They are generic requests about everyone’s data, not specific requests about a data subject’s data.
SE has a way to make data subject access requests, and it’s here, not on its public Meta site. If these questions had been posted there (and there’s no indication they have), SE would be obliged to respond.

I don't understand the logic behind your second point. Meta is an official communication channel that the company provides. There is NO WAY from the data request page to post an arbitrary question to the company. So, either you use Meta or a private EMail message to their "Contact Us" generic address.
Or... are you suggesting that one should make a Data Request about how to make a Data Request by abusing the "note" field on the page to post a generic question? That doesn't seem the intended use of the page

@SPArcheon-onstrike perhaps if you actually look at the data request form?

... I think this closes the door to further exchanges. Perhaps you didn't understand the issue, perhaps you don't want this discussion here, perhaps ...  I don't know. You are suggesting to use the Data request form - in quite a condescending way I may add - but if you noticed the point is exactly that some of the available options there aren't clear (art 12.1? Maybe). Again, I may trust you on the claim that the company is not required to explain its Data Request process (while I think that the EU Data Protection agency may disagree as it goes against the intent of 12.1 ) [cont]

[cont] but this still doesn't answer my question that you evaded with your condescending remarks: are you suggesting that questions about how to use the data request page must be filled thru the data request page? If so... care to say how you would do so? Select an option and then add a note that for example says "please tell me what data selling I can oppose to since you claim to not sell our data in your ToS?"
